# MySQL find results based on two different values of the same column

Tags: mysql

list employees names (Ename) who have both 49008 zip code customers and 49009 zip code customers.

I am struggling to answer the above query based on the above tables.

If the names match between tables assume constraint.

I can filter down to name and zip easily by left joins and group by but struggle after that, I don't know the proper where or having statement. I am assuming it could be done better by a sub query but not sure. Ideally, a single query.

Please and thank you.

1) Create and insert statements for example data:

```
Create table Employees (EM_Eno INT NOT NULL, EM_Ename VARCHAR(50), EM_Hire_Date DATE, PRIMARY KEY(EM_Eno));

Create table Customers (Customers_Cno INT NOT NULL, Customers_Cname VARCHAR(50), Customers_Street VARCHAR(50), Customers_Zip INT, Customers_Phone INT, primary key(Customers_Cno)); 

Create table Orders (Orders_Ono INT NOT NULL, Orders_Cno INT, Orders_Eno INT, Orders_Received DATE, Orders_Shipped DATE, primary key(Orders_Ono));


insert into Orders values
( 1,301,501,20161010,20161011);
( 2,302,501,20161011,20161012);
( 3,303,502,20161110,20161111);
( 4,304,502,20161110,20161112);
( 5,305,502,20161110,20161113);
( 6,306,503,20161112,20161114);
( 7,307,501,20161112,20161113);
( 8,308,503,20161112,20161115);
( 9,309,503,20161115,20161120);
(10,300,501,20161112,20161113);

insert into Customers values
(300,'Bryan','100 street',49009,1234567890),
(301,'Ryan','101 street',49008,1234567890),
(302,'Nick','102 street',49009,1234567890),
(303,'Nicholas','103 street',49009,1234567890),
(304,'Alexa','104 street',49009,1234567890),
(305,'Tori','105 street',49008,1234567890),
(306,'Scarlet','106 street',49008,1234567890),
(307,'Heather','100 street',49009,1234567890),
(308,'Amanda','107 street',49008,1234567890),
(309,'James','108 street',49008,1234567890);

insert into Employees values
(501,'Robert',20041010),
(502,'Sam',20050110),
(503,'Brandy',20050710);
```

2) Ideal end result is answering the query "list employees (names) who have both 49008-zipcode customers and 49009-zipcode customers."

3) Best Attempt thus far:

```
select Employees.EM_Ename
     , Customers.Customers_Zip 
  from Employees 
  left 
  join Orders 
    on Employees.EM_Eno = Orders.Orders_Eno 
  left 
  join Customers 
    on Orders.Orders_Cno = Customers.Customers_Cno 
 group 
    by Employees.EM_Ename
     , Customers.Customers_Zip;
```

Comment: Thank you for the guidance on how to properly request. I believe I have provided a more clear request. Let me know if it is still unclear.

Comment: where is a filter for values against rowset returns, having is a filter for groups against columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table names are altered slightly in the rextest, because other tables already exist there with the same name...

```
SELECT e.*
  FROM tbl_employees e
  JOIN tbl_orders o
    ON o.orders_eno = e.em_eno
  JOIN tbl_customers c
    ON c.Customers_Cno = o.Orders_Cno
 WHERE c.Customers_Zip IN(49008,49009)
 GROUP
    BY e.em_eno
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT customers_zip) = 2;
```

http://rextester.com/HCNLU51847

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you want:

```
select Min(e.Ename)
from #Employees e 
join #Orders o on o.Eno = e.Eno
join #Customers c on c.Cno = o.Cno
join #Orders o2 on o2.Eno = e.Eno
join #Customers c2 on c2.Cno = o2.Cno
where o.Ono !=o2.Ono--c.Cno != c2.Cno and 
and c.Zip = 49008 and c2.Zip = 49009
group by e.Ename,c.Zip
order by e.Ename
```

As you can see if you wanted more than those two the self joins become longer.